# Is "push to" correct in this context?

Tags: meaning, headlinese

the headline is:

"Rangers Push the Penguins to Game 7 in New York"

to me it is very confusing because the Rangers beat the Penguins, so the Rangers go to game 7 right? but when it says Rangers push Penguins to Game 7 it seems like Penguins got pushed into Game 7 and Rangers stayed behind of it. Do that headline make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

As a native American English speaker, it makes sense to me. The Penguins wished to avoid game 7 - meaning they won game 6. As they wanted to avoid game seven, the Rangers had to put effort into bringing them, or pushing them to, game 7. It’s less about physical location and more a metaphor for resistance and overcoming it.

Comment: I thought Game 7 was a desireble thing, Not anything to be avoided

Comment: Since it takes four games to win, game 7 is desirable if you're behind 3 games to 2 when about to play game 6, but not if you're ahead. Then you want to win right away. From the TV network's point of view, game 7 is very desirable. Lots of excitement, lots of viewers.